# Closeness of solutions of first and second-order ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to compare the solution of two ODEs, namely,
$$\varepsilon (t)y''(t) + a(t)y'(t)+\lambda y(t) = 0,\qquad y(0)=y_0,y'(0)=y'_0$$
with that of
$$ a(t)z'(t)+\lambda z(t) = 0, \qquad z(0)=y_0 $$
where $a,\varepsilon$ are continuous positive functions, $\lambda>0$, and $\varepsilon (t)\to 0$.

Since $\varepsilon$ becomes small, I would ideally like to obtain an upper bound of the form $\vert y(t)-z(t)\vert<g(t)$ with $g(t)\to 0$.

So far, I found the closed-form expression of $z$ and tried to plug it in the second-order ODE, but did not manage to get anything out of it.

Any tips or counter-example would be of great help, thank you!

Comment: It makes more sense to identify some kind of "scale" in $\varepsilon(t)$ i.e. write $\varepsilon(t)=\varepsilon f(t)$ for some $f(t)>0,f(t)=\Theta(1)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$) and then divide through by $f(t)$. After doing that, you can use the WKB method. Note that the result of the method will depend on how exactly you do this "splitting" of $\varepsilon(t)$ (even though the exact solution obviously does not).

Comment: I was not aware of the WKB method, I will look into it but this definitely seems helpful, thank you!